# Chain push along with filter, map etc in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function which returns an array which has filter, sort and map. How can I push a new item into the array before its sorted?

When I try the following I get an error saying push isnt a function.

```
return (
  myArray
    .filter((item) => {
      return item.value > 2;
    })
    .push(newThiny) // This doesn't work
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.name < b.name)
        return -1;
      if (a.name > b.name)
        return 1;
      return 0;
    })
    .map((item) => {
      return (
        <ChooseAnExercises
          key={item.name}
          name={item.name}
          active={item.active}
          setNumber={this.props.number}
          updateValue={this.props.updateValue}
        />
      )
    })
)
```

Comment: `.push(newThiny)` will return a `number` so `.sort` function will crash your code (sort works only on arrays).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.push(newThiny)` will return a `number` so `.sort` function will throw an error, since it doesn't work on `numbers`, only on arrays.

I would suggest you to use `.concat` instead.

`.concat(newThiny).sort({ ... })`

Answer (score 5):

> .push(newThiny) // This doesn't work

Push returns the length of the array rather than the array itself.

Rather than push try [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=a)

```
.concat([newThiny])
```

Answer (score 0):

`.push()` return a length of array. You can wrap your expression with `()`

See the Example:

```js
var arr = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

var arr2 = arr.filter( item => item > 2).push('Some');

console.log(arr2, 'doesnt works. You get the length of array');

(b = arr.filter(item => item > 2)).push('Some');

console.log(b, 'Works Correctly. In Array');
```